# Showing dynamic html content/image in Google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I'm new to this Google map integration.

I have the following code to add marker in Google map.

```
this.map.addMarker(this.createMarker(infoName, new window.google.maps.LatLng(data.MapdataRecord[i].Latitude, data.MapdataRecord[i].Longitude), 'icon_hosp.png'));
```

In above code we are showing hospital icon as a marker image, but now the requirement has changed and we need to show the dynamic content there.

Something like image/icon with Numbers. These numbers are dynamic. Reuirement is as below

[image]

How to add these markers in maps.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
onload google map make an array for your dyanamic icon.
while adding these marker on gmap.Add them
$.each(data.MapdataRecord,function(i,k){  
 this.map.addMarker(this.createMarker(infoName, new window.google.maps.LatLng(k.Latitude,     k.Longitude), Use Array of ICon));
});
```